# Apache Ignite Cache put fails with in the IgniteRunnable run method

Tags: ignite

I am getting the below error during the igniteCache.put() in the IgniteRunnable run()

I have only 2 nodes (client and server) .

1) Client creates the cache

```
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, LAttribute> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, LAttribute>();
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(Integer.class, LoanAttribute.class);
        cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        cfg.setName("inv_result");
        cfg.setCopyOnRead(false);   
        cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
```

2) Client Submit the IgniteRunnable task to Server

3) Client exit the cluster

**On the Server** (with in run() method)

1) Get the cache and put a value

```
    IgniteCache<Integer, LAttribute> iCache = Ignition.localIgnite().cache("inv_result");
    System.out.println("Begin .. "+iCache.size(CachePeekMode.ALL));     
    iCache.put(la.getId(), la);
```

**Error :**

```
[21:41:14,859][SEVERE][pub-#67%null%][GridJobWorker] Failed to execute job due to unexpected runtime exception [jobId=f4606f39b51-21c994a7-6b35-49fa-b696-582fa7825c31, ses=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=com.test.ignite.compute.AssetRestrictionComputeJob, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1492836063447, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, clsLdrId=438a5f39b51-76a937b0-7831-458b-aee4-cec662f02b0d, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionMap2, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=1], taskClsName=com.bfm.seclending.ignite.compute.AssetRestrictionComputeJob, sesId=c4606f39b51-21c994a7-6b35-49fa-b696-582fa7825c31, startTime=1492836072790, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=21c994a7-6b35-49fa-b696-582fa7825c31, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, internal=false, subjId=21c994a7-6b35-49fa-b696-582fa7825c31, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1492836072829, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, state=INIT]]], jobId=f4606f39b51-21c994a7-6b35-49fa-b696-582fa7825c31]]
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteInterruptedException: Failed to wait for asynchronous operation permit (thread got interrupted).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1440)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxy.java:2183)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.put(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1383)
    at co.test.ignite.compute.AssetRestrictionComputeJob.run(AssetRestrictionComputeJob.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C4V2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:2215)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:556)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6564)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:550)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:479)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1180)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1894)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1082)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1700(GridIoManager.java:102)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:673)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteInterruptedException: Failed to wait for asynchronous operation permit (thread got interrupted).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$3.apply(IgniteUtils.java:766)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$3.apply(IgniteUtils.java:764)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.asyncOpAcquire(GridCacheAdapter.java:4597)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:817)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1148)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.putAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:618)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:2541)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.put(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:595)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2215)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.put(IgniteCacheProxy.java:1376)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely server node was stopped in the middle of execution. That's the only case when internal Ignite threads are interrupted. When this happens, job can be automatically failed over to another node: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/fault-tolerance

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i have connected jvisualvm into the server node and see it is running . Few other observations below : 1) only the put() fails. 2) no issues with the get() 3) Also the put() fails on the IgniteRunnable in Server , it still works fine on the client.

Comment: In any case, you should check what interrupts the thread. `InterruptedException` is not an issue, it's a consequence of something else. From information you provided node stoppage is the only guess I can have.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the InterruptedException , executionService that i am using on the client side to submit the jobs is not waiting for the job completion .

when i call future.get() .. all good now. Thanks